# How to get a list value of `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use the below code of flask

`test_flag = db.session.query(TestTable.flag).distinct()`

It's SQL of `[SQL: SELECT DISTINCT test_table.flag AS test_table_flag  FROM test_table`

---

```
flag
1
2
3
```

How to get a list value of `db.session.query(TestTable.flag).distinct()`?

I need the output like this `[1,2,3]`, what I want to do is to ensure whether 2 is in [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to generate list of your `flags`

```
flag_list = [each.flag for each in db.session.query(TestTable.flag).distinct()]
```

---

Then you can use the below command to ensure whether `2` exist in `flag_list` or not. If it does exist then it will return `True` otherwise `False`

```
2 in flag_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the value on the database side, without having to retrieve all the distinct values.  This may be more efficient if you don't need all the values at the Python level, or if there are many rows in the table.

```py
# Assuming there are rows containing 1, 2 and 3.

flags = db.session.query(True).filter(db.exists().where(TestTable.flag == 2)).scalar()

flags = db.session.query(True).filter(db.exists().where(TestTable.flag == 4)).scalar()
```

The first query will return `True`, the second will return `None`.

Similarly, you could query for the count of rows with the required value to see if any exist, but the [exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists) construct is more efficient because it will stop searching after finding the first value that matches the filter.